# APK with same versionName but different versionCode

Tags: android, apk

Will the users get an update if I upload an APK with same versionName but different versionCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `versionName` is just something displayed to the user, from Google and Android perspective this field is simply ignored. The only relevant field is `versionCode`.

Therefore yes, users will get that update if only `versionCode` has changed.